# Enabling https for keycloak in docker-compose

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, keycloak, jhipster

I have generated an app using jhipster, and trying to configure keycloak for production (I am testing it on my local machine first), but I am struggling enabling https, please notice I want to connect keycloak to a local postgres database available on my pc. When I am starting the docker compose file, I am always getting that I need to enable https. The certificated are both .pem, generated on windows openssl.

this is keycloak.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1

    command: ['start', '--import-realm', '--hostname=localhost:9080',  '--http-relative-path=/auth', '--https-port=9443']
#    command: ['start', '--import-realm', '--hostname=localhost',  '--https-port=9443']
#    , '--hostname-strict-https=false'
    volumes:
    # the following line mounts the local realm config files into the keycloak container
      - ./realm-config:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./keycloak-themes/new/custom:/opt/keycloak/themes/custom
      - ./keycloak-themes/new/customKeycloak:/opt/keycloak/themes/customKeycloak
      - ./spi/keycloak-ip-authenticator.jar:/opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-ip-authenticator.jar
      - ./spi/spi-registration-profile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/keycloak/providers/spi-registration-profile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      # the following line is used to export a realm config
      - ./keycloak/realms/export:/tmp/export
      - ./keycloak/certs:/etc/ssl/certs/certs
    environment:
    
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=localhost:5432 # Replace with your external PostgreSQL host
      - DB_DATABASE=my-keycloak-db # Replace with your database name
      - DB_SCHEMA=public
      - DB_USER=<user> # Replace with your PostgreSQL username
      - DB_PASSWORD=<pass> # Replace with your PostgreSQL password
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=<admin>
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=<pass>
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=<user>
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<pass>
    
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/certs/localhostcert.pem
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_key_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/certs/localhostkey.pem
      - KC_HTTPS_PORT=9443
      
    ports:
      # - 127.0.0.1:9080:9080
      # - 127.0.0.1:9443:9443

      - 8080:9080
      - 9080:8080
      - 9443:9443
      - 443:8443
```

please let me know if anything missing although it could be outside the scope of the question